# How to identify if recording a macro will use absolute or relative references?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, recording

The user interface in Excel 2013 doesn't give a clue as whether the macro I'm about to record will be relative or absolute.
The pull down menu shows that option and toggles as you press, but the only way to find out is by then looking at the code.

Is there an easier way to identify whether I'm about to record a relative or an absolute macro?

Answer (score 2):

There is a color distinction between relative and absolute references when starting or during a macro recording. It is a 'toggle'; click once for On, click again for Off.

[image: record_relative_2013]         [image: record_absolute_2013]
          <sup>This starts the recorder in relative addressing</sup>            <sup>This starts the recorder in absolute addressing</sup>

During the recording this can be toggled on and off as necessary.

The Code group is found on the Developer tab. If you do not have a Developer ribbon tab, it can be added through File ► Options, Customize Ribbon.

Comment: Thanks.
I do see the icon, and I can see by its behavior that it toggles between absolute and relative. I can't tell the current state though. The icon is the same and the text is the same: Use Relative References.

I would think that MS would be kind enough to toggle the text or the floating message.

Comment: It comes down to the new(er) ribbon style. I admit that the older version made the current state more obvious (xl2007-xl2010 was an orange highlight) but turning relative addressing on and off has always been a toggle, even in pre-ribbon versions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

As I look closer to the icon (at least in Excel 2013), its "frame" is slightly different when its status is Relative: it has a very light green frame around the icon. Unlike 
When it's in absolute mode the frame remains white. Very difficult to tell the difference.

A suggestion to MS to toggle the text is in order. It doesn't cost much.
[image: See how you have to NOT select the option to see the difference]